# Postgres: pg_dump reports permission denied for large object xxxxx but cannot find it

Tags: postgresql

When doing `pg_dump` as a read-only user `readonly`, it reports an error:

```
pg_dump: could not open large object 19536: ERROR:  permission denied for large object 19536
```

Then I connect as the superuser `postgres`, but `SELECT * FROM pg_largeobject` returns nothing.

When I run `SELECT * FROM pg_largeobject_metadata WHERE oid=19536`, I get

```
lomowner    lomacl
10
```

Then with `SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE oid=10;` I get `postgres` which is me (also the superuser).

How can I find this large object and grant `SELECT` or whatever read privilege to user `readonly` so it can do pg_dump?

*Version: 11.4 (Ubuntu 11.4-1.pgdg18.04+1)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `pg_largeobject`, [`pg_largeobject_metadata`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-largeobject-metadata.html) can be read by all users and has one row per large object.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_largeobject_metadata WHERE oid = 19536;
```

The `lomowner` column holds the OID of the owner of the large object. If the account used for `pg_dump` is not superuser and not the owner of the large object and has not been granted rights to it, the failure to open it is expected.

---

> Then I connect as the superuser postgres, but SELECT * FROM
>   pg_largeobject returns nothing.

Having no row in pg_largeobject despite having large objects in
`pg_largeobject_metadata` is possible if the large objects are
all **empty** (their size is 0 byte).

Permissions on large objects can be granted individually with
a command like:

```
 GRANT SELECT ON LARGE OBJECT 19536 TO readonly;
```

I don't think there is any way to grant permissions to
all large objects, but alternatively the permissions checks on a database
can be neutralized entirely by a superuser with this command:

```
 ALTER DATABASE test SET lo_compat_privileges TO on;
```

Finally if you don't need that empty large object, it can be removed in SQL with

```
SELECT lo_unlink(19536);
```

Comment: The problem is I am the superuser as well as the owner, but `pg_largeobject` is still empty. And how to grant rights without knowing the object name?

Comment: @MylesFang: see edit